# Redshift copy JSON data with jsonpaths fails with not in correct json format error

Tags: json, copy, amazon-redshift

I am trying to load data into Redshift using a Firehose delivery stream.

I am using a jsonpaths file uploaded to S3 at the following location.

```
s3://my_bucket/jsonpaths.json
```

This file contains the following jsonpaths config

```
{
    "jsonpaths": [
        "$['col_1']",
        "$['col_2']",
        "$['col_3']",
        "$['col_4']"
    ]
}
```

To me this config looks ok, but the Firehose Redshift logs keep showing the following error.

```
"The provided jsonpaths file is not in a supported JSON format."
```

A similar error is seen even if I run the following copy command directly on the Redshift cluster.

```
reshift_db=# COPY my_schema.my_table 
FROM 's3://my_bucket/data.json' 
FORMAT JSON 's3://my_bucket/jsonpaths.json'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_iam_role=<role_arn>'
;
ERROR:  Manifest file is not in correct json format
DETAIL:  
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Manifest file is not in correct json format
  code:      8001
  context:   Manifest file location = s3://my_bucket/jsonpaths.json
  query:     yyyyy
  location:  s3_utility.cpp:338
  process:   padbmaster [pid=xxxxx]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

Can someone help with what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case was a [BOM (Byte Order Mark)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of the jsonpaths file. Some editors can save a file with BOM, and this does not show as characters when seen in the editor. And apparently Redshift does not like BOM at the beginning of the jsonpaths file.

For those of you who want to check if this is the case for your jsonpaths file, you can open the file in a hex editor. For the S3 file this can be done as follows.

```
# aws s3 cp s3://my_bucket/jsonpaths.json - | hexdump -C
```

To remove the BOM from the file you can do the following.

```
# aws s3 cp s3://my_bucket/jsonpaths.json - | dos2unix | aws s3 cp - s3://my_bucket/jsonpaths.json
```

Almost after 2 days of trying, and after having raised an AWS Support ticket, and having posted this question, it struct me that I should check the file in a hex editor.